# Submit form data, then submit again to add to database and send it on in PHP

Tags: php, html, forms

I'm trying to do something specific, and not entirely sure how to do it. Here's what I'm trying to do...

I have created a HTML form where the user specifies a URL, then enters a captcha code. The rest of the form is hidden, and sent with submit.

Upon successful submit, the form is sent to a local handler PHP file, which displays the information to the user for review, with another submit button. All of the form data on the handler page is hidden, because it's already been specified.

Upon successful second submit, the relevant form data is added to a database, and sent off to a secure 3rd party payment form. The only code I have control over are the initial form, and the confirmation form.

form.html - Gathers URL, and Captcha, then submits that, along with hidden form values
form2.php - Grabs all form values from form.html, echos them to the user for review. Adds to database, and submits to an outside form.

I'm not entirely sure how to make form 2 work properly. Instead of adding to the database on second submit, it's adding it on first submit, when form 2 is displayed.

Here is the second form below: (Please excuse the messy code!)

```
<?php
session_start();
if( ($_SESSION['security_code2']==$_POST['security_code2']) && (!empty($_POST['security_code2'])) ) { 
    //Get user submitted data for review
    $x_user1 = $_POST["domain"];
    $x_login = $_POST["x_login"];
    $x_show_form = $_POST["x_show_form"];
    $x_fp_sequence = $_POST["x_fp_sequence"];
    $x_fp_hash = $_POST["x_fp_hash"];
    $x_amount = $_POST["x_amount"];
    $x_currency_code = $_POST["x_currency_code"];
    $x_test_request = $_POST["x_test_request"];
    $x_relay_response = $_POST["x_relay_response"];
    $donation_prompt = $_POST["donation_prompt"];
    $x_line_item = $_POST["x_line_item"];
    $button_code = $_POST["button_code"];
    $x_show_form = $_POST["x_show_form"];
    echo "<!DOCTYPE html>
        <html>
            <head>
                <link rel=\"stylesheet\" type=\"text/css\" href=\"./css/redneck2.css\" />
                <link rel=\"stylesheet\" type=\"text/css\" href=\"./css/payments.css\" />
                <script>document.createElement(\"plist\")</script>
                <script>document.createElement(\"phead\")</script>
                <meta charset=\"UTF-8\">
                    <title>
                        Company Name - Confirm Selection
                    </title>
            </head>
            <body>
            <!-- begin main menu -->
                <nav>
                    <table id=\"menu1\">
                        <tr>
                            <td id=\"menu2\">
                                <a class=\"menutopleft\" href=\"index.html\">
                                    Home
                                </a>
                            </td>
                            <td id=\"menu2\">
                                <a class=\"menutopright\" href=\"faq.html\">
                                    F.A.Q.
                                </a>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td id=\"menu2\">
                                <a class=\"menu3\" href=\"new.html\">
                                    New
                                </a>
                            </td>
                            <td id=\"menu2\">
                                <a class=\"menu3\" href=\"soon.html\">
                                    Soon
                                </a>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td id=\"menu2\">
                                <a class=\"menu3\" href=\"terms.html\">
                                    Terms
                                </a>
                            </td>
                            <td id=\"menu2\">
                                <a class=\"menu3\" href=\"privacy.html\">
                                    Privacy
                                </a>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td id=\"menu2\">
                                <a class=\"menu3\" href=\"hardware.html\">
                                    Hardware
                                </a>
                            </td>
                            <td id=\"menu2\">
                                <a class=\"menu3\" href=\"tips.html\">
                                    Tips
                                </a>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td id=\"menu2\">
                                <a class=\"menu3\" href=\"alerts.html\">
                                    Alerts
                                </a>
                            </td>
                            <td id=\"menu2\">
                                <a class=\"menu3\" href=\"payments.html\">
                                    Payments
                                </a>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td id=\"menu2\">
                                <a class=\"menu4\" href=\"packages.html\">
                                    Packages
                                </a>
                            </td>
                            <td id=\"menu2\">
                                <a class=\"menu3\" href=\"status.html\">
                                    Status
                                </a>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td id=\"menu2\">
                                <a class=\"menu3\" href=\"testimonials.html\">
                                    Testimonials
                                </a>
                            </td>
                            <td id=\"menu2\">
                                <a class=\"menu3\" href=\"thanks.html\">
                                    Thanks
                                </a>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td id=\"menu2\">
                                <a class=\"menu3\" href=\"aboutus.html\">
                                    About Us
                                </a>
                            </td>
                            <td id=\"menu2\">
                                <a class=\"menu3\" href=\"./contactus/form.html\">
                                    Contact Us
                                </a>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td id=\"menu2\">
                                <a class=\"menu3\" href=\"tutorial.html\">
                                    Tutorial
                                </a>
                            </td>
                            <td id=\"menublank\">
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td id=\"menublank\">
                            </td>
                            <td id=\"menublank\">
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                    <table id=\"menufooter\">
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                <a href=\"index.html\">
                                    Powered by Company name
                                </a>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                Created by - creator
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </nav>
                <!-- end main menu -->
                <!-- begin header -->
                <header>
                    <a href=\"index.html\">
                        <img src=\"./images/banner1.jpg\">
                    </a>
                    <h1>
                        Packages
                    </h1>
                    <!--begin page menu -->
                    <table id=\"pagemenu1\">
                        <tr>
                            <td id=\"pagemenu2\">
                                <a class=\"pagemenu4tl\" href=\"packages.html\">
                                    Package 1
                                </a>
                            </td>
                            <td id=\"pagemenu2\">
                                <a class=\"pagemenu3\" href=\"packages2.html\">
                                    Package 2
                                </a>
                            </td>
                            <td id=\"pagemenu2\">
                                <a class=\"pagemenu3\" href=\"packages3.html\">
                                    Package 3
                                </a>
                            </td>
                            <td id=\"pagemenu2\">
                                <a class=\"pagemenu3\" href=\"packages4.html\">
                                    Package 4
                                </a>
                            </td>
                            <td id=\"pagemenu2\">
                                <a class=\"pagemenu3\" href=\"packages5.html\">
                                    Package 5
                                </a>
                            </td>
                            <td id=\"pagemenu2\">
                                <a class=\"pagemenu3tr\" href=\"packages6.html\">
                                    Specialty
                                </a>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td id=\"pagemenublankbl\">
                            </td>
                            <td id=\"pagemenublank\">
                            </td>
                            <td id=\"pagemenublank\">
                            </td>
                            <td id=\"pagemenublank\">
                            </td>
                            <td id=\"pagemenublank\">
                            </td>
                            <td id=\"pagemenublankbr\">
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                    <!-- end page menu -->
                </header>
                <!-- end header -->
                <section>
                    Below is information about our packages.
                    <hr>
                        <h3>
                            Please confirm your selection below!
                        </h3>
                        <p>
                            Package information
                        </p>
                        <p>
                            Package information goes here

                            <!-- Display user submitted URL -->
                            submitted URL: " . $x_user1 . "<br/>

                            <!-- Add second form, and insert database information -->

                            <!-- Begin confirmation form -->
                            <form action=\"3rdparty_handler\" method=\"POST\">
                                <input name=\"x_user1\" type=\"hidden\" value=\"" . $x_user1 . "\">
                                <input name=\"x_login\" type=\"hidden\" value=\"" . $x_login . "\">
                                <input name=\"x_show_form\" type=\"hidden\" value=\"" . $x_show_form . "\">
                                <input name=\"x_fp_sequence\" type=\"hidden\" value=\"" . $x_fp_sequence . "\">
                                <input name=\"x_fp_hash\" type=\"hidden\" value=\"" . $x_fp_hash . "\">
                                <input name=\"x_amount\" type=\"hidden\" value=\"" . $x_amount . "\">
                                <input name=\"x_currency_code\" type=\"hidden\" value=\"" . $x_currency_code . "\">
                                <input name=\"x_test_request\" type=\"hidden\" value=\"" . $x_test_request . "\">
                                <input name=\"x_relay_response\" type=\"hidden\" value=\"" . $x_relay_response . "\">
                                <input name=\"donation_prompt\" type=\"hidden\" value=\"" . $donation_prompt . "\">
                                <input name=\"x_line_item\" type=\"hidden\" value=\"" . $x_line_item . "\">
                                <input name=\"button_code\" type=\"hidden\" value=\"" . $button_code . "\">
                                <input id=\"paynow3\" type=\"submit\" value=\"Confirm\">
                            <!-- End confirmation form -->                                  
                        </p>
                    </section>
                    <!--Begin Footer -->
                    <footer>
                        <p>
                            <table id=\"pagefooter\">
                                <tr>
                                    <td>
                                        <a href=\"index.html\">
                                            Powered by Company name
                                        </a>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>
                                        Created by creator
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            </table>
                        </p>
                    </footer>
                    <!-- End Footer -->
                </body>
            </html>";
    //Begin Customer number, and URL retrieval

    //Specify database information
    $servername = "localhost";
    $dbuser = "dbuser";
    $dbpassword = "dbpassword";
    $dbname = "dbname";

    //Create connection
    $conn = new mysqli($servername, $dbuser, $dbpassword, $dbname);

    // Check Connection
    if ($conn->connect_error) {
        die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
    }

    // Insert customer number, and package number in database
    $sql = "INSERT INTO CustomerNumber (package,domain)
    VALUES ('1','$x_user1')";

    if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
        $x_po_num = $conn->insert_id;
        echo ('<input name="x_po_num" value="' . $x_po_num . '" type="hidden">' );
    }
        else {
            echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
        }

    // Close connection
    $conn->close();
    //End customer number, and URL retrieval
}
else {
    echo "<!DOCTYPE html>
        <html>
            <head>
                <link rel=\"stylesheet\" type=\"text/css\" href=\"./css/redneck2.css\" />
                <link rel=\"stylesheet\" type=\"text/css\" href=\"./css/payments.css\" />
                <script>document.createElement(\"plist\")</script>
                <script>document.createElement(\"phead\")</script>
                <meta charset=\"UTF-8\">
                    <title>
                        Company name - Confirm Selection
                    </title>
            </head>
            <body>
            <!-- begin main menu -->
                <nav>
                    <table id=\"menu1\">
                        <tr>
                            <td id=\"menu2\">
                                <a class=\"menutopleft\" href=\"index.html\">
                                    Home
                                </a>
                            </td>
                            <td id=\"menu2\">
                                <a class=\"menutopright\" href=\"faq.html\">
                                    F.A.Q.
                                </a>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td id=\"menu2\">
                                <a class=\"menu3\" href=\"new.html\">
                                    New
                                </a>
                            </td>
                            <td id=\"menu2\">
                                <a class=\"menu3\" href=\"soon.html\">
                                    Soon
                                </a>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td id=\"menu2\">
                                <a class=\"menu3\" href=\"terms.html\">
                                    Terms
                                </a>
                            </td>
                            <td id=\"menu2\">
                                <a class=\"menu3\" href=\"privacy.html\">
                                    Privacy
                                </a>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td id=\"menu2\">
                                <a class=\"menu3\" href=\"hardware.html\">
                                    Hardware
                                </a>
                            </td>
                            <td id=\"menu2\">
                                <a class=\"menu3\" href=\"tips.html\">
                                    Tips
                                </a>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td id=\"menu2\">
                                <a class=\"menu3\" href=\"alerts.html\">
                                    Alerts
                                </a>
                            </td>
                            <td id=\"menu2\">
                                <a class=\"menu3\" href=\"payments.html\">
                                    Payments
                                </a>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td id=\"menu2\">
                                <a class=\"menu4\" href=\"packages.html\">
                                    Packages
                                </a>
                            </td>
                            <td id=\"menu2\">
                                <a class=\"menu3\" href=\"status.html\">
                                    Status
                                </a>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td id=\"menu2\">
                                <a class=\"menu3\" href=\"testimonials.html\">
                                    Testimonials
                                </a>
                            </td>
                            <td id=\"menu2\">
                                <a class=\"menu3\" href=\"thanks.html\">
                                    Thanks
                                </a>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td id=\"menu2\">
                                <a class=\"menu3\" href=\"aboutus.html\">
                                    About Us
                                </a>
                            </td>
                            <td id=\"menu2\">
                                <a class=\"menu3\" href=\"./contactus/form.html\">
                                    Contact Us
                                </a>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td id=\"menu2\">
                                <a class=\"menu3\" href=\"tutorial.html\">
                                    Tutorial
                                </a>
                            </td>
                            <td id=\"menublank\">
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td id=\"menublank\">
                            </td>
                            <td id=\"menublank\">
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                    <table id=\"menufooter\">
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                <a href=\"index.html\">
                                    Powered by Company name
                                </a>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                Created by creator
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </nav>
                <!-- end main menu -->
                <!-- begin header -->
                <header>
                    <a href=\"index.html\">
                        <img src=\"./images/banner1.jpg\">
                    </a>
                    <h1>
                        Packages
                    </h1>
                    <!--begin page menu -->
                    <table id=\"pagemenu1\">
                        <tr>
                            <td id=\"pagemenu2\">
                                <a class=\"pagemenu4tl\" href=\"packages.html\">
                                    Package 1
                                </a>
                            </td>
                            <td id=\"pagemenu2\">
                                <a class=\"pagemenu3\" href=\"packages2.html\">
                                    Package 2
                                </a>
                            </td>
                            <td id=\"pagemenu2\">
                                <a class=\"pagemenu3\" href=\"packages3.html\">
                                    Package 3
                                </a>
                            </td>
                            <td id=\"pagemenu2\">
                                <a class=\"pagemenu3\" href=\"packages4.html\">
                                    Package 4
                                </a>
                            </td>
                            <td id=\"pagemenu2\">
                                <a class=\"pagemenu3\" href=\"packages5.html\">
                                    Package 5
                                </a>
                            </td>
                            <td id=\"pagemenu2\">
                                <a class=\"pagemenu3tr\" href=\"packages6.html\">
                                    Specialty
                                </a>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td id=\"pagemenublankbl\">
                            </td>
                            <td id=\"pagemenublank\">
                            </td>
                            <td id=\"pagemenublank\">
                            </td>
                            <td id=\"pagemenublank\">
                            </td>
                            <td id=\"pagemenublank\">
                            </td>
                            <td id=\"pagemenublankbr\">
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                    <!-- end page menu -->
                </header>
                <!-- end header -->
                <section>
                    Below is information about our available packages.
                    <hr>
                        <h3>
                            Invalid Security Captcha String!<br/>
                            Please use your browser's back button to go back, and try again.
                        </h3>
                        <p>
                        </p>
                    </section>
                    <!--Begin Footer -->
                    <footer>
                        <p>
                            <table id=\"pagefooter\">
                                <tr>
                                    <td>
                                        <a href=\"index.html\">
                                            Powered by Company name
                                        </a>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>
                                        Created by creator
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            </table>
                        </p>
                    </footer>
                    <!-- End Footer -->
                </body>
            </html>";
}
?>
```

Comment: It's inserting after the first submit because you placed it in the second step. You need to create a third step, where you combine inserting into the database along with a redirection to the remote site. That's how I'd do it.

Comment: You're suggesting a 3rd page that would automatically add it to the database, submit the form data, and redirect to the 3rd party?

Comment: Kind of. At least you need to place the `INSERT` into another script. As redirecting `POST` data isn't possible, I'd outsource the `INSERT`, then do an AJAX request to the outsourced script _right before_ submitting the form to the 3rd party handler. So: User clicks the submit button -> `onSubmit` does an AJAX request to the script, which inserts the data into the database -> finally submit the form to the third party handler. That's at least how I'd do it.

Comment: I have no clue how to do that. lol I'm actually just in the process of teaching myself PHP just to get this far. I've never even looked at AJAX code before.

Comment: @MarcelloMönkemeyer Wow... I never got back to this because I never got any kind of notification. I kinda figured it out. This form never got completed, but I figured out that the way to do it is have one file that contains the forms, and the handler code.

In the form i did use, I had a number of conditionals that were based on which form was submitted. I just put the database related stuff on the second form handler to only be executed if the second form is submitted.